# The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified

Tags: json, ajax, twitter, docusignapi

Hi can someone please help here.Below is the request and error:
**Error**
"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
**JSOn  Request :**

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
var creds = JSON.stringify({
    Username: "Sam Spade",
    Password: "secret",
    IntegratorKey: "axxxx6-4ea9-4aaaf3d-9287-6cebe8231849"
});

...

request.setRequestHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);
```

looks fine.

But you are also sending OAuth authentication credentials via:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer 29Diokb4VuiEA/W/F/FTyywW1f4=");
```

That's the problem. Either use `X-DocuSign-Authentication` for authentication or `Authorization` for OAuth authentication, but not both.

**Added**

Also, no need for these headers:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Origin","https://apiexplorer.docusign.com");
request.setRequestHeader("Referer","https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/");
request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
```

And I'm not sure why you're adding these:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4");
```

Answer (score 0):

- A sample key/value example for "X-DocuSign-Authentication" is below:

  "X-DocuSign-Authentication": {"Username":"myemail@domain.com","Password":"pwdhere","IntegratorKey":"removed"}

Please ensure that the format matches with the appropriate double quotes.

- Please note that you will want to get a new integrator key. The IK should never be shared publicly.